# RouteServiceProvider can't find query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to make seo friendly url with slugs of post. So what I have made so far is this in my `RouteServiceProvider`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Post;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
      
        parent::boot();
        
        Route::bind('post', function($slug){ 
            return Post::published()->where('slug')->first();
        });
    }
```

This in my BlogController

```
public function show(Post $post){
    
    return view("blog.show", compact('post'));
}
```

When I go to the post http://example.com/slug-from-database I've got the error

> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 426:
>
> No query results for model [App\Post].

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: Just want to check, do you have a model called `Post` with a namespace of `App\Post`?

Comment: Yes, I have. I can post it also but I don't thing is relevant with the issue here.

Comment: I notice you are specifying a namespace in your service provider could this be trying to find your `Post` model in `App\Http\Controllers\Post`?. Without more of the output from the error it is a little hard to tell. It's a bit of a long shot tbh

Comment: This `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';` is the default file after laravel installation. I didn't added it. If I remove this line I've got error that can't find the controller instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `$slug` in your `WHERE` clause, here:

```
Route::bind('post', function($slug){ 
    return Post::published()->where('slug')->first();
});
```

Change the query like this and it will work:

```
Post::published()->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```